# How to use CheckBox in the menu in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Android. I want to use a checkbox in the menu which has to be checked and unchecked while the user touching. And I need to perform some actions if the check box is checked. Right now I have a checkbox that is checked when the program is run.

I have managed to insert checkbox in the menu and got it to be checked when the app starts, just as it should. But when I try to uncheck it, the program crashes.

Menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Allow Check"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_help"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Hai"/>

        <item
             android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
             android:showAsAction="never" 
             android:title="Allow Check 2" 
             android:checkable="true"
             android:checked="true" />
    </menu>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
    {
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = this.MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
            }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId) {
            case Resource.Id.action_help:
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox1:
                CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)FindViewById (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
//Here the check1 come as null, which leads to the crash.
                if (check1.Checked == true)
                    check1.Checked = false;
                else
                    check1.Checked = true;
                check1.Click += check1_Click;
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox2:
                CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)FindViewById (Resource.Id.checkBox2);
                if (check2.Checked == true)
                    check2.Checked = false;
                else
                    check2.Checked = true;
                check2.Click += check2_Click;
                return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
                }
        }
```

While trying to retrieve the checkbox declared in the menu, it comes as null. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use code snippet , may this help you

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId) {
            case Resource.Id.action_help:
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox1:

                if (item.IsChecked)
                    item.SetChecked(false);
                else
                    item.SetChecked(true);
                item.Click += check1_Click;
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox2:

                if (item.IsChecked)
                    item.SetChecked(false);
                else
                    item.SetChecked(true);
                item.Click += check2_Click;
                return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
                }
        }
```

Comment: there might be chances that some issue in code , I have native java code ready , if you want i post that too, Thanks

Comment: This works.! Thanks poor. However as you said there were few changes in API names. But the idea worked for me. I have edited your answer to runnable form which worked for me.

Comment: Good,  nice to hear ,if help then please accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the checked state of the item by calling `item.IsChecked` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach those controls in you `OnCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private CheckBox check1;
    private CheckBox check2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.yourLayout);

        //find controls in here
        check1 = (CheckBox)FindViewById (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        check2 = (CheckBox)FindViewById (Resource.Id.checkBox2);
    }
```

....
and then do your checks

```
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId) {
            case Resource.Id.action_help:
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox1:                    
                if (check1.Checked == true)
                    check1.Checked = false;
                else
                    check1.Checked = true;
                check1.Click += check1_Click;
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.checkBox2:
                if (check2.Checked == true)
                    check2.Checked = false;
                else
                    check2.Checked = true;
                check2.Click += check2_Click;
                return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
                }
    }
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. "FindViewById (Resource.Id.checkBox1)" returns null. I dont know why.